# gVisOrgChart not displaying child nodes

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, googlevis, orgchart

I have been trying to plot a gVisOrgChart but some child nodes are not visible in the final output even though they exist in the data. Is there a maximum size of characters that child nodes can hold in the Output ?

I have tried adjusting the width of the nodes as well but still not able to visualize the complete output.

I have described the data and output in the below link:

https://github.com/mages/googleVis/issues/84